# Sums of reciprocals of primes in an arithmetic progression

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $y>x\geq 1$, $p_0\geq x$. Consider $$S=\mathop{\sum_{x\leq p\leq y}}_{p\equiv a \mod p_0} \frac{1}{p}.$$By Brun-Titchmarsh and (basically) integration by parts, I seem to get that $$S \leq \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{p_0-1} \left(\log \log \frac{y}{p_0} + \frac{1}{\log \frac{y}{p_0}}\right) \leq \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{x-1} \left(\log \log \frac{y}{x} + \frac{1}{\log \frac{y}{x}}\right) .$$ moreover, the term $1/\log(y/x)$ can be eliminated for $y/x$ larger than a constant.

Bounds like this one should be standard. What is the strongest or cleanest result in the literature? Perhaps $S\leq \frac{1}{x} + \frac{2}{x} \log \log \frac{y}{x}$ for $x>2$ and $y/x\geq e^{e^{1/6}} = 3.258\dotsc$, say? Or $S\leq \frac{2}{x} \log \log y$ for $y\geq x>e^{e^{1/2}}=5.200\dotsc$?

(The naïve guess would be something like $S\leq \frac{1}{x} (1 + \log \frac{\log y}{\log x})$. A very cursory search in the literature on my part has only yielded Remark 1 in section 2 of Pomerance, On the distribution of amicable numbers, 1976.)